# 3D helix torus with hidden lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, 3d, asymptote, pst-solides3d

[image: Torus wrapped with helix]

How can I generate the above image using `TikZ` (possibly other methods will work if they produce better looking results)?
I would like to have a nicely shaded (not so dark image) *without* gridlines and possibly enough opacity on the torus to see the hidden part of the helix.

The image given is very close to what I want though and I would just try to make it visually a little better.

Comment: Just in case it might be useful, [here's the Maple worksheet](http://www.smallfiles.org/download/2079/torus.mw.html) that I used to generate that image.

Comment: I guess hidden curves can be dealt with structure `sketeton` of Asymptote. https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/72e506ec/#4c65/ab5d

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here's a Sketch/TikZ approach.

[image]

Running `sketch` on this file:

```
def helix {
    def n_segs 600
  sweep [draw=orange] { n_segs, rotate(24*360 / n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1]), rotate(1*360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0]) } (2.01,0,0)
}

def torus {
    def n_segs 60
    sweep [draw=none, fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.75] {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0])}
        sweep {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1])}
        (2,0,0)
}

put { view((10,4,2)) } {{helix} {torus}}

global { language tikz }
```

generates a `.tex` file which can be compiled using `pdflatex`.

The helix winding around the helix winding around a torus

[image]

can be generated using

```
def helix {
    def n_segs 10000
  sweep [draw=orange] {
    n_segs,
    rotate(1000*360 / n_segs, (2,0,0), [0,1,0]),
    rotate(24*360 / n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1]),
    rotate(1*360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0])
  } (2.04,0,0)
}

def torus {
    def n_segs 50
    sweep [draw=none, fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.75] {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0])}
        sweep {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1])}
        (1.9,0,0)
}

put { view((10,4,2)) } {{torus} {helix}}

global { language tikz }
```

Comment: How _big_ is the TikZ file? :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Hehe, I tried posting it, but the system wouldn't let me. It's about 250kB, so not much fun to edit by hand. The resulting PDF is 47kB.

Comment: I'm impressed: draws faster than the PSTrick one!

Comment: OK. Thanks for your effort. I am still waiting for the pure TikZ. If it is impossible then I will assign you the bounty.

Comment: Wow. The helix winding around the other winding around the torus is incredible. This is most likely impossible in a 'normal' graphics program such as Illustrator or Inkscape and quite hard even in Blender or other 3D programs.

Comment: @Alexander: I made one with Mathematica several years ago.

Comment: It looks very nice! If the torus could have some shading then it would look more real though!

Answer (score 47):

The example shows the function

```
 x(u,v)=(R1 + (R0 +RL*sin(u))*sin(k*v))*cos(v)-RL*cos(u)*sin(v)
 y(u,v)=(R1 + (R0 +RL*sin(u))*sin(k*v))*sin(v)+RL*cos(u)*cos(v)
 z(u,v)=(R0 + RL*sin(u))*cos(k*v)
```

with the parameter setting shown in the example. 
RL: radius of the coil line; R1: Torus outer; R0: Torus inner radius; k:number of coils

run it with `xelatex` or `latex>dvips>ps2pdf` (takes some time to run!)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-6,-4)(6,4)
\psset{viewpoint=30 0 15 rtp2xyz,Decran=30,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSolid[object=tore,r1=5,r0=1,ngrid=36 36,
    fillcolor=blue!30,action=none,name=Torus]%
%\axesIIID(4.5,4.5,0)(5,5,4)
\codejps{/R1 5 def /RL 0.05 def /R0 1.1 def /k 25 def}%
\defFunction[algebraic]{helix}(u,v)
    {(R1 + (R0 +RL*sin(u))*sin(k*v))*cos(v)-RL*cos(u)*sin(v)}
    {(R1 + (R0 +RL*sin(u))*sin(k*v))*sin(v)+RL*cos(u)*cos(v)}
    {(R0 + RL*sin(u))*cos(k*v)}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
       base=0 6.2831853 0 6.2831853,
       linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.01,fillcolor=yellow,
       ngrid=0.8 0.01,function=helix,action=none,name=Helix]%
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=Torus Helix,grid=false]
%\gridIIID[Zmin=-3,Zmax=3,showAxes=false](-2,2)(-2,2)
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-6,-6)(6,6)
\psset{viewpoint=30 0 90 rtp2xyz,Decran=30,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSolid[object=tore,r1=5,r0=1,ngrid=36 36,
    fillcolor=blue!30,action=none,name=Torus]%
%\axesIIID(4.5,4.5,0)(5,5,4)
\codejps{/R1 5 def /RL 0.05 def /R0 1.1 def /k 25 def}%
\defFunction[algebraic]{helix}(u,v)
    {(R1 + (R0 +RL*sin(u))*sin(k*v))*cos(v)-RL*cos(u)*sin(v)}
    {(R1 + (R0 +RL*sin(u))*sin(k*v))*sin(v)+RL*cos(u)*cos(v)}
    {(R0 + RL*sin(u))*cos(k*v)}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
       base=0 6.2831853 0 6.2831853,
       linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.01,fillcolor=yellow,
       ngrid=0.8 0.01,function=helix,action=none,name=Helix]%
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=Torus Helix,grid=false]
%\gridIIID[Zmin=-3,Zmax=3,showAxes=false](-2,2)(-2,2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

an animation is here: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Animation/gif/gif

With `\psSolid[object=fusion,base=Torus Helix,grid=false,opacity=0.5]`  (setting transparency) and a thinner helix (decrease /RL) one gets

[image]

and just for fun with

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-6.5,-3.5)(6.5,3)
\psset{viewpoint=30 0 15 rtp2xyz,Decran=30,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSolid[object=tore,r1=5,r0=1,ngrid=36 36,tablez=0 0.05 1 {} for,
          zcolor= 1 .5 .5 .5 .5 1,action=none,name=Torus]
\pstVerb{/R1 5 def /R0 1.2 def /k 20 def /RL 0.15 def /kRL 40 def}%
\defFunction[algebraic]{helix}(t)
     {(R1+R0*cos(k*t))*sin(t)+RL*sin(kRL*k*t)}
     {(R1+R0*cos(k*t))*cos(t)+RL*cos(kRL*k*t)}
     {R0*sin(k*t)+RL*sin(kRL*k*t)}
\psSolid[object=courbe,
        resolution=7800,
        fillcolor=black,incolor=black,
        r=0,
        range=0 6.2831853,
        function=helix,action=none,name=Helix]%
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=Torus Helix,grid]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to fix the artifacts where the yellow helix seems to be missing in the first picture? I would also like to use a parameteric curve instead of a solid(I tried to modify the code but always get errors). I'd like the yellow helix to look more like a grid line on the torus rather than a separate object.

Comment: `\pstVerb{/R1 5 def /R0 1.2 def /k 20 def /RL 0.1 def /kRL 40 def}%`

Comment: then you have not the current `pst-solides3d.tex|pro` files. Compare with the ones from http://texnik.dante.de/

Comment: I am also having trouble obtaining the image above. I update the pst-solides3d.tex / pro files from the website you mention. Should I also update the rubans files ?

Comment: see my edited answer with the current file list, which can be read at the end of the logfile.

Answer (score 21):

**Updated:** Includes workarounds for previous difficulties with compiling complex paths.

Here's an Asymptote approach that allows nth order helixes. I show examples of a first-order helix (which wraps once around the torus, as in the original question), a second-order helix, and a third-order helix.

Here's the code (configured for a first-order helix):

```
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 16;
settings.prc = false;
real unit = 2cm;
unitsize(unit);

import graph3;

void drawsafe(path3 longpath, pen p, int maxlength = 400) {
  int length = length(longpath);
  if (length <= maxlength) draw(longpath, p);
  else {
    int divider = floor(length/2);
    drawsafe(subpath(longpath, 0, divider), p=p, maxlength=maxlength);
    drawsafe(subpath(longpath, divider, length), p=p, maxlength=maxlength);
  }
}

struct helix {
  path3 center;
  path3 helix;
  int numloops;
  int pointsperloop = 12;
  /* t should range from 0 to 1*/
  triple centerpoint(real t) {
    return point(center, t*length(center));
  }
  triple helixpoint(real t) {
    return point(helix, t*length(helix));
  }
  triple helixdirection(real t) {
    return dir(helix, t*length(helix));
  }
  /* the vector from the center point to the point on the helix */
  triple displacement(real t) {
    return helixpoint(t) - centerpoint(t);
  }
  bool iscyclic() {
    return cyclic(helix);
  }
}

path3 operator cast(helix h) {
  return h.helix;
}

helix helixcircle(triple c = O, real r = 1, triple normal = Z) {
  helix toreturn;
  toreturn.center = c;
  toreturn.helix = Circle(c=O, r=r, normal=normal, n=toreturn.pointsperloop);
  toreturn.numloops = 1;
  return toreturn;
}

helix helixAbout(helix center, int numloops, real radius) {
  helix toreturn;
  toreturn.numloops = numloops;
  from toreturn unravel pointsperloop;
  toreturn.center = center.helix;
  int n = numloops * pointsperloop;
  triple[] newhelix;
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    real theta = (i % pointsperloop) * 2pi / pointsperloop;
    real t = i / n;
    triple ihat = unit(center.displacement(t));
    triple khat = center.helixdirection(t);
    triple jhat = cross(khat, ihat);
    triple newpoint = center.helixpoint(t) + radius*(cos(theta)*ihat + sin(theta)*jhat);
    newhelix.push(newpoint);
  }
  toreturn.helix = graph(newhelix, operator ..);
  return toreturn;
}

int loopfactor = 20;
real radiusfactor = 1/8;
helix wrap(helix input, int order, int initialloops = 10, real initialradius = 0.6, int loopfactor=loopfactor) {
  helix toreturn = input;
  int loops = initialloops;
  real radius = initialradius;
  for (int i = 1; i <= order; ++i) {
    toreturn = helixAbout(toreturn, loops, radius);
    loops *= loopfactor;
    radius *= radiusfactor;
  }
  return toreturn;
}

currentprojection = perspective(12,0,6);

helix circle = helixcircle(r=2, c=O, normal=Z);

/* The variable part of the code starts here. */
int order = 1;    // This line varies.
real helixradius = 0.5;
real safefactor = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < order; ++i)
  safefactor -= radiusfactor^i;
real saferadius = helixradius * safefactor;

helix todraw = wrap(circle, order=order, initialradius = helixradius);    // This line varies (optional loopfactor parameter).

surface torus = surface(Circle(c=2X, r=0.99*saferadius, normal=-Y, n=32), c=O, axis=Z, n=32);
material toruspen = material(diffusepen=gray, ambientpen=white);
draw(torus, toruspen);

drawsafe(todraw, p=0.5purple+linewidth(1pt));  // This line varies (linewidth only).
```

The output:

[image]

For a second-order helix, change the last portion of the above code to the following:

```
/* The variable part of the code starts here. */
int order = 2;    // This line varies.
real helixradius = 0.5;
real safefactor = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < order; ++i)
  safefactor -= radiusfactor^i;
real saferadius = helixradius * safefactor;

helix todraw = wrap(circle, order=order, initialradius = helixradius, loopfactor=40);    // This line varies (optional loopfactor parameter).

surface torus = surface(Circle(c=2X, r=0.99*saferadius, normal=-Y, n=32), c=O, axis=Z, n=32);
material toruspen = material(diffusepen=gray, ambientpen=white);
draw(torus, toruspen);

drawsafe(todraw, p=0.5purple+linewidth(0.6pt));  // This line varies (linewidth only).
```

The output:

[image]

For a third-order helix, change the "variable" portion of the code to the following:

```
/* The variable part of the code starts here. */
int order = 3;    // This line varies.
real helixradius = 0.5;
real safefactor = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < order; ++i)
  safefactor -= radiusfactor^i;
real saferadius = helixradius * safefactor;

helix todraw = wrap(circle, order=order, initialradius = helixradius);    // This line varies (optional loopfactor parameter).

surface torus = surface(Circle(c=2X, r=0.99*saferadius, normal=-Y, n=32), c=O, axis=Z, n=32);
material toruspen = material(diffusepen=gray, ambientpen=white);
draw(torus, toruspen);

drawsafe(todraw, p=0.5purple+linewidth(0.2pt));  // This line varies (linewidth only).
```

The output:

[image]

One final comment: the rendering mechanism in Asymptote for translucent surfaces does not do a good job with more than one layer of translucent surface (i.e., when a translucent surface is obscuring another translucent surface (or piece of one)).  Here's an example of the difficulty:

[image]

This is a bit less noticeable in mrc's answer, but it's still there, at least for now.

However, this difficulty can be mitigated (when only one surface is involved and it has no self-intersections) by sorting the constituent patches so that they are drawn in order of distance from the camera:

[image]

```
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 16;
settings.prc = false;
real unit = 2cm;
unitsize(unit);

import graph3;

void drawsafe(path3 longpath, pen p, int maxlength = 400) {
  int length = length(longpath);
  if (length <= maxlength) draw(longpath, p);
  else {
    int divider = floor(length/2);
    drawsafe(subpath(longpath, 0, divider), p=p, maxlength=maxlength);
    drawsafe(subpath(longpath, divider, length), p=p, maxlength=maxlength);
  }
}

void sort(surface s) {
  projection P = currentprojection;
  //The following code is copied from three_surface.asy
  // Sort patches by mean distance from camera
  triple camera=P.camera;
  if(P.infinity) {
    triple m=min(s);
    triple M=max(s);
    camera=P.target+camerafactor*(abs(M-m)+abs(m-P.target))*unit(P.vector());
  }

  real[][] depth=new real[s.s.length][];
  for(int i=0; i < depth.length; ++i)
    depth[i]=new real[] {abs(camera-s.s[i].cornermean()),i};

  depth=sort(depth);
  //end of copied code

  int[] permutation = sequence(new int(int i) {return (int)depth[i][4];}, depth.length);

  int[][] inversionTool = new int[permutation.length][5];
  for (int i = 0; i < permutation.length; ++i)
    inversionTool[i] = new int[] {permutation[i], i};
  inversionTool = sort(inversionTool);
  int inverse(int i) {return inversionTool[i][6];};

  patch[] sortedS = new patch[depth.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < sortedS.length; ++i) {
    sortedS[i] = s.s[permutation[i]];
  }
  s.s = sortedS;

  for (int[] currentrow : s.index)
    for (int i = 0; i < currentrow.length; ++i)
      currentrow[i] = inverse(currentrow[i]);
}

struct helix {
  path3 center;
  path3 helix;
  int numloops;
  int pointsperloop = 12;
  /* t should range from 0 to 1*/
  triple centerpoint(real t) {
    return point(center, t*length(center));
  }
  triple helixpoint(real t) {
    return point(helix, t*length(helix));
  }
  triple helixdirection(real t) {
    return dir(helix, t*length(helix));
  }
  /* the vector from the center point to the point on the helix */
  triple displacement(real t) {
    return helixpoint(t) - centerpoint(t);
  }
  bool iscyclic() {
    return cyclic(helix);
  }
}

path3 operator cast(helix h) {
  return h.helix;
}

helix helixcircle(triple c = O, real r = 1, triple normal = Z) {
  helix toreturn;
  toreturn.center = c;
  toreturn.helix = Circle(c=O, r=r, normal=normal, n=toreturn.pointsperloop);
  toreturn.numloops = 1;
  return toreturn;
}

helix helixAbout(helix center, int numloops, real radius) {
  helix toreturn;
  toreturn.numloops = numloops;
  from toreturn unravel pointsperloop;
  toreturn.center = center.helix;
  int n = numloops * pointsperloop;
  triple[] newhelix;
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    real theta = (i % pointsperloop) * 2pi / pointsperloop;
    real t = i / n;
    triple ihat = unit(center.displacement(t));
    triple khat = center.helixdirection(t);
    triple jhat = cross(khat, ihat);
    triple newpoint = center.helixpoint(t) + radius*(cos(theta)*ihat + sin(theta)*jhat);
    newhelix.push(newpoint);
  }
  toreturn.helix = graph(newhelix, operator ..);
  return toreturn;
}

int loopfactor = 20;
real radiusfactor = 1/8;
helix wrap(helix input, int order, int initialloops = 10, real initialradius = 0.6, int loopfactor=loopfactor) {
  helix toreturn = input;
  int loops = initialloops;
  real radius = initialradius;
  for (int i = 1; i <= order; ++i) {
    toreturn = helixAbout(toreturn, loops, radius);
    loops *= loopfactor;
    radius *= radiusfactor;
  }
  return toreturn;
}

currentprojection = perspective(12,0,6);

helix circle = helixcircle(r=2, c=O, normal=Z);

/* The variable part of the code starts here. */
int order = 1;    // This line varies.
real helixradius = 0.5;
real safefactor = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < order; ++i)
  safefactor -= radiusfactor^i;
real saferadius = helixradius * safefactor;

helix todraw = wrap(circle, order=order, initialradius = helixradius);    // This line varies (optional loopfactor parameter).

surface torus = surface(Circle(c=2X, r=0.99*saferadius, normal=-Y, n=32), c=O, axis=Z, n=32);
sort(torus);
material toruspen = material(diffusepen=gray + opacity(0.5), ambientpen=white);
draw(torus, toruspen);

drawsafe(todraw, p=0.4magenta+linewidth(1pt));  // This line varies (linewidth only).
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I was wondering about that---it's incredibly noticeable for opacity(0.9), but I chose opacity(0.3) to minimize the weirdness.

Comment: Also: I'm trying to get better at `asymptote`. Would you mind explaining the idea behind your approach a little bit? I was going to just come up with the parametric equation for the 2nd order curve (following http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143897/wrapping-curves) but that got way too complicated . . .

Comment: @mrc: As discussed in the question you link to, the key to wrapping a curve by a helix is to have a moving frame. In my approach, I assume that the curve to be wrapped (say, **v**(t)) was itself constructed as a helix (the "center" **c**(t)). I also assume that when both curves are reparametrized so that t ranges from 0 to 1, the vector from **c**(t) to **v**(t) is orthogonal to **v'**(t). Thus, this vector provides the **i**(t) vector (called `ihat` in the code), **v'**(t) provides **k**(t), and **j**(t) is obtained as a cross product. Once we have a continuous moving frame,...

Comment: ... the new helix is parametrized as `h(t) = i cos(t) + j sin(t)`. The only reason I use `path3`s for the intermediate helixes rather than functions of type `triple(real)` is so that I can use the function `dir(path3, real)`, which returns the unit tangent vector to the path at the specified `t`-value.

Comment: @mrc: You might be interested in my newest addition to this answer.

Answer (score 20):

Here's an approach using `asymptote`. It's pretty basic, but if you open it in Adobe Reader you can rotate the torus!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{asy}[width=0.5\textwidth]
import graph3;

size(200,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(4,0,2);

//inner radius
real R=2;
//outer radius
real a=0.75;

//surface:
triple f(pair t) {
  return ((R+a*cos(t.y))*cos(t.x),(R+a*cos(t.y))*sin(t.x),a*sin(t.y));
}

//path:
real x(real t) {return cos(t/15)*(R + a*cos(t));}
real y(real t) {return sin(t/15)*(R + a*cos(t));}
real z(real t) {return a*sin(t);}

pen p=blue+opacity(0.33);
// make surface and path
surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2pi,2pi),8,8,Spline);
path3 q=graph(x,y,z,0,30*pi,operator ..);

// draw surface and path
draw(s,p);
draw(q);

\end{asy}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Here's a work-in-progress. It's missing the most important thing: the visibility of the helix. At first I thought that the points where it becomes (in)visible are evenly spaced, but they are not quite. I think I'll  have to do some vector algebra to (hopefully) find a solution. The torus is not a 3D object, it's made from many almost transparent circular rings.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\xangle}{-30}
\newcommand{\yangle}{210}
\newcommand{\zangle}{90}

\newcommand{\xlength}{1}
\newcommand{\ylength}{1}
\newcommand{\zlength}{1}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{\xlength*cos(\xangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xy}{\xlength*sin(\xangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yx}{\ylength*cos(\yangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\ylength*sin(\yangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zx}{\zlength*cos(\zangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zy}{\zlength*sin(\zangle)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   x={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},
    y={(\yx cm,\yy cm)},
    z={(\zx cm,\zy cm)},
]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\RO}{1.1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RI}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\K}{10}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\doubleRO}{2*\RO}

\foreach \h in {0,0.01,...,\doubleRO}
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\pm}{sqrt(\h*(\doubleRO-\h))}
    \fill[opacity=0.007,blue,even odd rule] (0,0,\h-\RO) circle (\RI+\pm) (0,0,\h-\RO) circle (\RI-\pm);
}

\xdef\initialx{\RI}
\xdef\initialy{0}
\xdef\initialz{\RO}

\foreach \v in {0.1,0.2,...,360.1}
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{(\RI + \RO*sin(\K*\v))*cos(\v)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newy}{(\RI + \RO*sin(\K*\v))*sin(\v)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newz}{\RO*cos(\K*\v)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{cos(\v)*50+50}
    \draw[red!\mycolor!green,thick] (\initialx,\initialy,\initialz) -- (\newx,\newy,\newz);
    \xdef\initialx{\newx}
    \xdef\initialy{\newy}
    \xdef\initialz{\newz}

}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### (insufficient) Result

[image]

Comment: if you want hidden lines and surfaces then you have to build small line or polygon segments of all objects, then build the direction vector and sort all calculated vectors. And in the end you have to fill the canvas with the line and polygon segments depending to the sorted list of direction vectors.

Comment: see my deleted answer for the same limitations using `pgfplots`

Comment: The torus is nice and you got the windings. Maybe put a solid black torus behind the blue one so it looks shaded rather than glowing