# How can I visualize a Torus with three paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I would like to show a Torus with three paths on its surface:

[image]

- Both points ($a$ and $b$) are on the surface of the torus.
- All three paths (orange, red, green) are on the surface of the torus
- All three paths start in $a$ and end in $b$
- The orange and the red path are pretty "straight" (one goes the left side, one the right side, but the green path is more interesting. It makes a "curve" (I really don't know how to describe this better.

The torus was created with sketch:

```
def torus {
    def n_segs 40
    sweep [draw=black, fill=lightgray, fill opacity=0.75] {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (0,0,0), [0,1,0])}
        sweep {n_segs, rotate(360/n_segs, (1.5,0,0), [0,0,1])}
        (2,0,0)
}

put { view((10,4,2)) } {{torus}}

global { language tikz }
```

How can I print the paths on the torus?

Comment: Check out the related )to the right).  Expccially http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70090/3d-helix-torus-with-hidden-lines?rq=1

Comment: Dou you have a parametrization of your curves? I would like to try to draw that directly in tikz tomorrow.

Comment: @Ronny: No, I don't have a parametrization of my curves.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is an answer that uses Asymptote to produce a vector graphic result:
[image]

The actual pdf file may be found, for now, at [this location](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/torus_paths_tools.pdf); but I don't think you will have any trouble compiling it (although it may take a while--about 77 seconds on my computer). I've omitted the LaTeX wrapper and divided the code into two code blocks for readability, but you can just copy and paste them one after the other to make a coherent `.asy` file.

The first code block is really an Asymptote module I am writing that is in its very early stages:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";

import graph3;
import contour;

// A bunch of auxiliary functions.

real fuzz = .001;

real umin(surface s) { return 0; }
real vmin(surface s) { return 0; }
pair uvmin(surface s) { return (umin(s), vmin(s)); }
real umax(surface s, real fuzz=fuzz) {
  if (s.ucyclic()) return s.index.length;
  else return s.index.length - fuzz;
}
real vmax(surface s, real fuzz=fuzz) {
  if (s.vcyclic()) return s.index[0].length;
  return s.index[0].length - fuzz;
}
pair uvmax(surface s, real fuzz=fuzz) { return (umax(s,fuzz), vmax(s,fuzz)); }

typedef real function(real, real);

function normalDot(surface s, triple eyedir(triple)) {
  real toreturn(real u, real v) {
    return dot(s.normal(u, v), eyedir(s.point(u,v)));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

struct patchWithCoords {
  patch p;
  real u;
  real v;
  void operator init(patch p, real u, real v) {
    this.p = p;
    this.u = u;
    this.v = v;
  }
  void operator init(surface s, real u, real v) {
    int U=floor(u);
    int V=floor(v);
    int index = (s.index.length == 0 ? U+V : s.index[U][V]);

    this.p = s.s[index];
    this.u = u-U;
    this.v = v-V;
  }
  triple partialu() {
    return p.partialu(u,v);
  }
  triple partialv() {
    return p.partialv(u,v);
  }
}

typedef triple paramsurface(pair);

paramsurface tangentplane(surface s, pair pt) {
  patchWithCoords thepatch = patchWithCoords(s, pt.x, pt.y);
  triple partialu = thepatch.partialu();
  triple partialv = thepatch.partialv();
  return new triple(pair tangentvector) {
    return s.point(pt.x, pt.y) + (tangentvector.x * partialu) + (tangentvector.y * partialv);
  };
}

guide[] normalpathuv(surface s, projection P = currentprojection, int n = ngraph) {
  triple eyedir(triple a);
  if (P.infinity) eyedir = new triple(triple) { return P.camera; };
  else eyedir = new triple(triple pt) { return P.camera - pt; };
  return contour(normalDot(s, eyedir), uvmin(s), uvmax(s), new real[] {0}, nx=n)[0];
}

path3 onSurface(surface s, path p) {
  triple f(int t) {
    pair point = point(p,t);
    return s.point(point.x, point.y);
  }

  guide3 toreturn = f(0);
  paramsurface thetangentplane = tangentplane(s, point(p,0));
  triple oldcontrol, newcontrol;
  int size = length(p);
  for (int i = 1; i <= size; ++i) {
    oldcontrol = thetangentplane(postcontrol(p,i-1) - point(p,i-1));
    thetangentplane = tangentplane(s, point(p,i));
    newcontrol = thetangentplane(precontrol(p, i) - point(p,i));
    toreturn = toreturn .. controls oldcontrol and newcontrol .. f(i);
  }

  if (cyclic(p)) toreturn = toreturn & cycle;

  return toreturn;

}

/*
 * This method returns an array of paths that trace out all the
 * points on s at which s is parallel to eyedir.
 */

path[] paramSilhouetteNoEdges(surface s, projection P = currentprojection, int n = ngraph) {
   guide[] uvpaths = normalpathuv(s, P, n);
  //Reduce the number of segments to conserve memory
  for (int i = 0; i < uvpaths.length; ++i) {
    real len = length(uvpaths[i]);
    uvpaths[i] = graph(new pair(real t) {return point(uvpaths[i],t);}, 0, len, n=n);
  }
  return uvpaths;
}   

private typedef real function2(real, real);
private typedef real function3(triple);

triple[] normalVectors(triple dir, triple surfacen) {
  dir = unit(dir);
  surfacen = unit(surfacen);
  triple v1, v2;
  int i = 0;
  do {
    v1 = unit(cross(dir, (unitrand(), unitrand(), unitrand())));
    v2 = unit(cross(dir, (unitrand(), unitrand(), unitrand())));
    ++i;
  } while ((abs(dot(v1,v2)) > Cos(10) || abs(dot(v1,surfacen)) > Cos(5) || abs(dot(v2,surfacen)) > Cos(5)) && i < 1000);
  if (i >= 1000) {
    write("problem: Unable to comply.");
    write(" dir = " + (string)dir);
    write(" surface normal = " + (string)surfacen);
  }
  return new triple[] {v1, v2};
}

function3 planeEqn(triple pt, triple normal) {
  return new real(triple r) {
    return dot(normal, r - pt);
  };
}

function2 pullback(function3 eqn, surface s) {
  return new real(real u, real v) {
    return eqn(s.point(u,v));
  };
}

/*
 * returns the distinct points in which the surface intersects
 * the line through the point pt in the direction dir
 */

triple[] intersectionPoints(surface s, pair parampt, triple dir) {
  triple pt = s.point(parampt.x, parampt.y);
  triple[] lineNormals = normalVectors(dir, s.normal(parampt.x, parampt.y));
  path[][] curves;
  for (triple n : lineNormals) {
    function3 planeEn = planeEqn(pt, n);
    function2 pullback = pullback(planeEn, s);
    guide[] contour = contour(pullback, uvmin(s), uvmax(s), new real[]{0})[0];

    curves.push(contour);
  }
  pair[] intersectionPoints;
  for (path c1 : curves[0])
    for (path c2 : curves[1])
      intersectionPoints.append(intersectionpoints(c1, c2));
  triple[] toreturn;
  for (pair P : intersectionPoints)
    toreturn.push(s.point(P.x, P.y));
  return toreturn;
}



/*
 * Returns those intersection points for which the vector from pt forms an
 * acute angle with dir.
 */
 int numPointsInDirection(surface s, pair parampt, triple dir, real fuzz=.05) {
  triple pt = s.point(parampt.x, parampt.y);
  dir = unit(dir);
  triple[] intersections = intersectionPoints(s, parampt, dir);
  int num = 0;
  for (triple isection: intersections)
    if (dot(isection - pt, dir) > fuzz) ++num;
  return num;
}

bool3 increasing(real t0, real t1) {
  if (t0 < t1) return true;
  if (t0 > t1) return false;
  return default;
}

int[] extremes(real[] f, bool cyclic = f.cyclic) {
  bool3 lastIncreasing;
  bool3 nextIncreasing;
  int max;
  if (cyclic) {
    lastIncreasing = increasing(f[-1], f[0]);
    max = f.length - 1;
  } else {
    max = f.length - 2;
    if (increasing(f[0], f[1])) lastIncreasing = false;
    else lastIncreasing = true;
  }
  int[] toreturn;
  for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) {
    nextIncreasing = increasing(f[i], f[i+1]);
    if (lastIncreasing != nextIncreasing) {
      toreturn.push(i);
    }
    lastIncreasing = nextIncreasing;
  }
  if (!cyclic) toreturn.push(f.length - 1);
  toreturn.cyclic = cyclic;
  return toreturn;
}

int[] extremes(path path, real f(pair) = new real(pair P) {return P.x;})
{
  real[] fvalues = new real[size(path)];
  for (int i = 0; i < fvalues.length; ++i) {
    fvalues[i] = f(point(path, i));
  }
  fvalues.cyclic = cyclic(path);
  int[] toreturn = extremes(fvalues);
  fvalues.delete();
  return toreturn;
}

path[] splitAtExtremes(path path, real f(pair) = new real(pair P) {return P.x;})
{
  int[] splittingTimes = extremes(path, f);
  path[] toreturn;
  if (cyclic(path)) toreturn.push(subpath(path, splittingTimes[-1], splittingTimes[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i+1 < splittingTimes.length; ++i) {
    toreturn.push(subpath(path, splittingTimes[i], splittingTimes[i+1]));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

path[] splitAtExtremes(path[] paths, real f(pair P) = new real(pair P) {return P.x;})
{
  path[] toreturn;
  for (path path : paths) {
    toreturn.append(splitAtExtremes(path, f));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

path3 toCamera(triple p, projection P=currentprojection, real fuzz = .01, real upperLimit = 100) {
  if (!P.infinity) {
    triple directionToCamera = unit(P.camera - p);
    triple startingPoint = p + fuzz*directionToCamera;
    return startingPoint -- P.camera;
  }
  else {
    triple directionToCamera = unit(P.camera);
    triple startingPoint = p + fuzz*directionToCamera;

    return startingPoint -- (p + upperLimit*directionToCamera);
  }
}

int numSheetsHiding(surface s, pair parampt, projection P = currentprojection) {
  triple p = s.point(parampt.x, parampt.y);
  path3 tocamera = toCamera(p, P);
  triple pt = beginpoint(tocamera);
  triple dir = endpoint(tocamera) - pt;
  return numPointsInDirection(s, parampt, dir);
}

struct coloredPath {
  path path;
  pen pen;
  void operator init(path path, pen p=currentpen) {
    this.path = path;
    this.pen = p;
  }
  /* draws the path with the pen having the specified weight (using colors)*/
  void draw(real weight) {
    draw(path, p=weight*pen + (1-weight)*white);
  }
}
coloredPath[][] layeredPaths;
// onTop indicates whether the path should be added at the top or bottom of the specified layer
void addPath(path path, pen p=currentpen, int layer, bool onTop=true) {
  coloredPath toAdd = coloredPath(path, p);
  if (layer >= layeredPaths.length) {
    layeredPaths[layer] = new coloredPath[] {toAdd};
  } else if (onTop) {
    layeredPaths[layer].push(toAdd);
  } else layeredPaths[layer].insert(0, toAdd);
}

void drawLayeredPaths() {
  for (int layer = layeredPaths.length - 1; layer >= 0; --layer) {
    real layerfactor = (1/3)^layer;
    for (coloredPath toDraw : layeredPaths[layer]) {
      toDraw.draw(layerfactor);
    }
  }
}

real[] cutTimes(path tocut, path[] knives) {
  real[] intersectionTimes = new real[] {0, length(tocut)};
  for (path knife : knives) {
    real[][] complexIntersections = intersections(tocut, knife);
    for (real[] times : complexIntersections) {
      intersectionTimes.push(times[0]);
    }
  }
  return sort(intersectionTimes);
}

path[] cut(path tocut, path[] knives) {
  real[] cutTimes = cutTimes(tocut, knives);
  path[] toreturn;
  for (int i = 0; i + 1 < cutTimes.length; ++i) {
    toreturn.push(subpath(tocut,cutTimes[i], cutTimes[i+1]));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

real[] condense(real[] values, real fuzz=.001) {
  values = sort(values);
  values.push(infinity);
  real previous = -infinity;
  real lastMin;
  real[] toReturn;
  for (real t : values) {
    if (t - fuzz > previous) {
      if (previous > -infinity) toReturn.push((lastMin + previous) / 2);
      lastMin = t;
    }
    previous = t;
  }
  return toReturn;
}

/*
 * A smooth surface parametrized by the domain [0,1] x [0,1]
 */
struct SmoothSurface {
  surface s;
  private real sumax;
  private real svmax;
  path[] paramSilhouette;
  path[] projectedSilhouette;
  projection theProjection;

  path3 onSurface(path paramPath) {
    return onSurface(s, scale(sumax,svmax)*paramPath);
  }

  triple point(real u, real v) { return s.point(sumax*u, svmax*v); }
  triple point(pair uv) { return point(uv.x, uv.y); }
  triple normal(real u, real v) { return s.normal(sumax*u, svmax*v); }
  triple normal(pair uv) { return normal(uv.x, uv.y); }

  void operator init(surface s, projection P=currentprojection) {
    this.s = s;
    this.sumax = umax(s);
    this.svmax = vmax(s);
    this.theProjection = P;
    this.paramSilhouette = scale(1/sumax, 1/svmax) * paramSilhouetteNoEdges(s,P);
    this.projectedSilhouette = sequence(new path(int i) {
    path3 truePath = onSurface(paramSilhouette[i]);
    path projectedPath = project(truePath, theProjection, ninterpolate=1);
    return projectedPath;
      }, paramSilhouette.length);
  }

  int numSheetsHiding(pair parampt) {
    return numSheetsHiding(s, scale(sumax,svmax)*parampt);
  }

  void drawSilhouette(pen p=currentpen, bool includePathsBehind=false, bool onTop = true) {
    int[][] extremes;
    for (path path : projectedSilhouette) {
      extremes.push(extremes(path));
    }

    path[] splitSilhouette;
    path[] paramSplitSilhouette;

    /*
     * First, split at extremes to ensure that there are no
     * self-intersections of any one subpath in the projected silhouette.
     */

    for (int j = 0; j < paramSilhouette.length; ++j) {
      path current = projectedSilhouette[j];

      path currentParam = paramSilhouette[j];

      int[] dividers = extremes[j];
      for (int i = 0; i + 1 < dividers.length; ++i) {
    int start = dividers[i];
    int end = dividers[i+1];
    splitSilhouette.push(subpath(current,start,end));
    paramSplitSilhouette.push(subpath(currentParam, start, end));
      }
    }

    /*
     * Now, split at intersections of distinct subpaths.
     */

    for (int j = 0; j < splitSilhouette.length; ++j) {
      path current = splitSilhouette[j];
      path currentParam = paramSplitSilhouette[j];

      real[] splittingTimes = new real[] {0,length(current)};
      for (int k = 0; k < splitSilhouette.length; ++k) {
    if (j == k) continue;
    real[][] times = intersections(current, splitSilhouette[k]);
    for (real[] time : times) {
      real relevantTime = time[0];
      if (.01 < relevantTime && relevantTime < length(current) - .01) splittingTimes.push(relevantTime);
    }
      }
      splittingTimes = sort(splittingTimes);
      for (int i = 0; i + 1 < splittingTimes.length; ++i) {
    real start = splittingTimes[i];
    real end = splittingTimes[i+1];
    real mid = start + ((end-start) / (2+0.1*unitrand()));
    pair theparampoint = point(currentParam, mid);
    int sheets = numSheetsHiding(theparampoint);

    if (sheets == 0 || includePathsBehind) {
      path currentSubpath = subpath(current, start, end);
      addPath(currentSubpath, p=p, onTop=onTop, layer=sheets);
    }

      }
    }
  }

  /*
    Splits a parametrized path along the parametrized silhouette,
    taking [0,1] x [0,1] as the
    fundamental domain.  Could be implemented more efficiently.
  */
  private real[] splitTimes(path thepath) {
    pair min = min(thepath);
    pair max = max(thepath);
    path[] baseknives = paramSilhouette;
    path[] knives;
    for (int u = floor(min.x); u < max.x + .001; ++u) {
      for (int v = floor(min.y); v < max.y + .001; ++v) {
    knives.append(shift(u,v)*baseknives);
      }
    }
    return cutTimes(thepath, knives);
  }

  /*
    Returns the times at which the projection of the given path3 intersects
    the projection of the surface silhouette. This may miss unstable
    intersections that can be detected by the previous method.
  */
  private real[] silhouetteCrossingTimes(path3 thepath, real fuzz = .01) {
    path projectedpath = project(thepath, theProjection, ninterpolate=1);
    real[] crossingTimes = cutTimes(projectedpath, projectedSilhouette);
    if (crossingTimes.length == 0) return crossingTimes;
    real current = 0;
    real[] toReturn = new real[] {0};
    for (real prospective : crossingTimes) {
      if (prospective > current + fuzz
      && prospective < length(thepath) - fuzz) {
    toReturn.push(prospective);
    current = prospective;
      }
    }
    toReturn.push(length(thepath));
    return toReturn;
  }

  void drawSurfacePath(path parampath, pen p=currentpen, bool onTop=true) {
    path[] toDraw;
    real[] crossingTimes = splitTimes(parampath);
    crossingTimes.append(silhouetteCrossingTimes(onSurface(parampath)));
    crossingTimes = condense(crossingTimes);
    for (int i = 0; i+1 < crossingTimes.length; ++i) {
      toDraw.push(subpath(parampath, crossingTimes[i], crossingTimes[i+1]));
    }
    for (path thepath : toDraw) {
      pair midpoint = point(thepath, length(thepath) / (2+.1*unitrand()));
      int sheets = numSheetsHiding(midpoint);
      path path3d = project(onSurface(thepath), theProjection, ninterpolate = 1);
      addPath(path3d, p=p, onTop=onTop, layer=sheets);
    }
  }
}
```

The second code block is the code that uses the utilities defined above to actually draw a torus. It bears a certain resemblance to the code from my previous (rasterized-only) answer.

```
real unit = 4cm;
unitsize(unit);
triple eye = (10,1,4);
//currentprojection=perspective(2*eye);
currentprojection=orthographic(eye);

surface torus = surface(Circle(c=2Y, r=0.6, normal=X, n=32), c=O, axis=Z, n=32);
torus.ucyclic(true);
torus.vcyclic(true);

SmoothSurface Torus = SmoothSurface(torus);

Torus.drawSilhouette(p=black, includePathsBehind=true);

pair a = (22/40, 3/40);
pair b = (5/40, .5);

path abpathparam(int ucycles, int vcycles) {
  pair bshift = (ucycles, vcycles);
  pair f(real t) {
    return (1-t)*a + t*(b+bshift);
  }
  return graph(f, 0, 1, n=10);
}

real linewidth = 0.8pt;

Torus.drawSurfacePath(abpathparam(0,0), p=linewidth + orange);
Torus.drawSurfacePath(abpathparam(1,0), p=linewidth + red);
Torus.drawSurfacePath(abpathparam(1,-1), p=linewidth + (darkgreen + 0.2blue));

pen meshpen = gray(0.6);
for (real u = 0; u < 1; u += 1/40) {
  Torus.drawSurfacePath(graph(new pair(real v) {return (u,v);}, 0,1,n=5), p=meshpen, onTop=false);
}
for (real v = 0; v < 1; v += 1/20) {
  Torus.drawSurfacePath(graph(new pair(real u) {return (u,v);}, 0, 1, n=5), p=meshpen, onTop=false);
}

drawLayeredPaths();

dot(project(Torus.point(a.x,a.y)), L="$a$", align=W);
dot(project(Torus.point(b.x,b.y)), L="$b$", align=N);
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks for putting so much work in this image (it's now part of my free [lecture notes for geometry and topology](http://tinyurl.com/geotopo)). In the evening, I will try to compile it. If it works, I'll give you a bounty. (By the way, the image at your university site looks great.)

Comment: When I try to compile this, I get `error: out of memory`.

Comment: @moose: I've put a fair amount of effort into getting rid of those errors, but I guess it makes sense that different installations will behave differently. If you use `/*`...`*/` to comment out all the lines strictly between `Torus.drawSilhouette` and `drawLayeredPaths();`, what happens?

Comment: It compiles (to a quite crappy image) and gives: `next.asy: 539.26: no matching variable 'a.x'
next.asy: 539.30: no matching variable 'a.y'`

Comment: Commenting `for (real u = 0; u < 1; u += 1/40) {
  Torus.drawSurfacePath(graph(new pair(real v) {return (u,v);}, 0,1,n=10), p=meshpen, onTop=false);
}` out resolved the error.

Comment: When I change the two increments to `1/10` and `1/5` it works ... but the image does not look as good as yours.

Comment: @moose: Try changing `n=10` to `n=5` in both the `for` loops (but with the original increments).

Comment: Changing `n=10` to `n=5` did not work.

Comment: @moose: Try also adding the parameter `n=10` at the end of the `abpathparam` function, as in the modified answer.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Unfortunately, I get an out-of-memory-error, too (Win7 64bit, 6GB RAM, Asymptote 2.24).

Comment: @Philipp: Interesting--I'm fairly sure the memory constraint here is an Asymptote quirk rather than a system limitation, since my system has less RAM than yours. I suppose you could try using Asymptote 2.23 (which is what I'm using), but I doubt it will make a difference.

Comment: @Philipp: I've opened a discussion [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/ce22fc4e/) about this issue. Anyone who has experienced the problem should feel free to contribute additional information to help isolate it.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks for opening the discussion. Maybe it is related to Windows because when I watch the memory usage while running your asymptote script the out-of-memory-error occurs when the Asymptote process uses about 275 MB of memory. That sounds much too low to cause an error. But I don't know enough about that to get to any useful conclusion.

Comment: @Philipp: I don't think it's exclusively a Windows thing; what you report is consistent with the sort of behavior I have seen on out-of-memory-errors with earlier versions of this code.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I don't know if this helps to isolate the problem but when I try to compile your "torus wrapped in a helix" solution from [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135438/6870) answer of yours I get an out-of-memory-error while "the first image (with the two circles)" solution does compile without problems (but, then again, it only uses 200 MB of memory).

Comment: @Philipp: I've just looked at the statistics on my machine. Running this answer, the memory usage never goes above 86 MB. So it may be a Windows thing after all. In particular, my code relies on garbage collection to keep the memory usage in check; if the Windows version lacks this feature, then the memory usage for this code will be exorbitant.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks for checking this on your machine. I did another test on an old notebook of mine (Windows XP, 1 GB RAM) where I have Asymptote 2.16 installed. I got the same results as for my Windows 7 PC: Both torus examples that didn't work before gave an out-of-memory-error again (when reaching around 275 MB of memory consumption) while the one example that worked before did also work on this machine (with a memory consumption of about 200 MB). When I get to it I will also test it on a Linux machine.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Could you please also create an example like this: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/nPWQu0U.png)? All three dots are on the surface of the torus. $s_3$ is in the inner part, $s_2$ at the top and $s_1$ at the outer part. This is an example for gaussian curvature.

Comment: @moose: The example may be found [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/more_torus_paths.pdf). The code is [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/more_torus_paths.asy); it requires [this auxiliary code](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/surfacepaths.asy) to be saved in a file in the same directory.

Answer (score 19):

How's this?

[image]

The code using `asymptote`:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.render = 8;
settings.prc = false;

import graph3;
import contour;
size3(8cm);

currentprojection = orthographic(10,1,4);
defaultrender = render(merge = true);

// create torus as surface of rotation
int umax = 40;
int vmax = 40;
surface torus = surface(Circle(c=2Y, r=0.6, normal=X, n=vmax), c=O, axis=Z, n=umax);
torus.ucyclic(true);
torus.vcyclic(true);

pen meshpen = 0.3pt + gray;

draw(torus, surfacepen=material(diffusepen=white+opacity(0.6), emissivepen=white));
for (int u = 0; u < umax; ++u)
  draw(torus.uequals(u), p=meshpen);
for (int v = 0; v < vmax; ++v)
  draw(graph(new triple(real u) {return torus.point(u,v); }, 0, umax, operator ..),
       p=meshpen);

pair a = (floor(umax/2) + 2, 3);
dot(torus.point(a.x, a.y), L="$a$", align=W);
pair b = (5, floor(vmax/2));
dot(torus.point(b.x, b.y), L="$b$", align=2Z + X);

path3 abpath(int ucycles, int vcycles) {
  pair bshift = (ucycles*umax, vcycles*vmax);
  triple f(real t) {
    pair uv = (1-t)*a + t*(b+bshift);
    return torus.point(uv.x, uv.y);
  }
  return graph(f, 0, 1, operator ..);
}

real linewidth = 0.8pt;

draw(abpath(0,0), p=linewidth + orange);
draw(abpath(1,0), p=linewidth + red);
draw(abpath(1,-1), p=linewidth + darkgreen);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A great answer! But when I try to compile it, I get an error: `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/asymptote/three.asy: 2906.13: runtime: to support onscreen rendering, please install glut library, run ./configure, and recompile`. Currently, I update Texlive and hope it fixes the problem, because I didn't find glut within the repository (I use Linux Mint).

Comment: Updating texlive didn't help. `freeglut3` is installed. What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: @moose: I wish I knew enough to help, in part because if I did, then I might have some chance of manually updating Asymptote on my own machine. All I know is that for me, after installing  MacTeX, Asymptote magically works.

Comment: @moose: I do have one suggestion, which may or may not be helpful. Make sure that whatever workflow you are using is calling `asy` without the `-V` option; the error you are getting may be an error in the preview mechanism rather than the mechanism for producing a pdf file.

Comment: I have a workflow that works for at least one [asymptote example](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/asymptote/torus-three-paths). Could you please upload the compiled pdf somewhere? I would like to use this in my lecture notes, but I really don't know how I can get it work (except recompiling everything by myself ... but that might cause other problems and not work).

Comment: @moose: Is there a reason you cannot use the png file in this answer (scaled down by a factor of 8)? The pdf file would be rasterized in any case, so it would not actually give any additional information; in fact, it would probably be worse unless I took steps to make it output the full computed resolution (which the png format does automatically).

Comment: Why would the PDF be rasterized? (The reason I've asked for a PDF is that I would like to insert vector graphics)

Comment: @moose: When rendering 3d graphics as vector graphics, Asymptote has much more limited capabilities for hidden surface removal, at least for the moment. Try the same source code with `settings.render = 0;` instead of `8`; you will probably be able to compile it successfully, and the result will be a vector graphic, but the green path will look like it's on top of the torus all the way.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Sorry to wake you up again for this. I just wanted to know where do we control the length of the trajectory that goes from a to b. How to choose an arbitrary path let's say from a to a that is by continuing the same path from a to b (as in your fig) then b to a again (by continuing along with winding around the torus)? Hope I am clear

Comment: @Shamina The `torus.point` function provides a map from the plane to the torus. So you need construct a function from a real interval to R^2 (in the code above I use line segments) and then compose that function with `torus.point` to get a path on the torus. Note that if two points differ by integer coordinates in the plane, they will map to the same point on the torus. So, for instance, a line segment from (0,0) to (0,1) will wind once around the torus and end up back at the starting place; a line segment from (0,0) to (0, 2) will wind twice; etc. Hope that helps!

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks for this. I have two naive questions. Is it possible to generate the same kind of figure like your second answer? I mean in there the other side of the torus is bit transparent making a nice contrast of a 3D object. Other thing is it possible to show two kind of wind here? (where in one the winding takes place only along outer circumference (bigger circle) and in another case along inside circle (orthogonal to previous one, smaller circle), this would surely be very helpful, if you can say something about it. Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: @Shamina: Both answers have the other side of the torus a bit transparent; the only difference is whether it produces vector graphics or rasterized. For the two kinds of wind: a path from (0,0) to (1,0) will show one kind of wind; a path from (0,0) to (0,1) will show the other.

Comment: Thanks! But when I try to compile your code using .asy format (by removing the environment `\begin{}...` I couldn't get the 3D contrast. I am pretty sure I'm missing something very simple? I could not compile it otherwise

Comment: This where I made changes for the winding (at the last): [link](https://pastebin.com/PZSbxbVH). I'm sure I'm making some naive mistake, I'm sorry to take your so much precious time.