# How to draw toroidal grid diagrams in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-knots

I am trying to turn a planar grid diagram into a 3D toroidal graph by identifying the top edge with the bottom and the left with the right, i.e:

[image]

So the grid below on the left would be transformed into a right-hand trefoil knot on a torus:
[image] 
[image]

I would like to draw a torus which looks like this but with the grid structure (including the grid itself, the o's, the x's, and the red lines). Could I please have some help. Many thanks in advance!

Edit: I have created a 'torus' out of A4 for illustration - would like the x's and o's to be placed in certain unit grids and the red lines to be straight like in the original grid diagram:
[image]

Comment: Like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus ?

Comment: Most of it is not too difficult to achieve but the 3d shading of blue thing that wraps around it is comparatively tough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The quadrant problem is resolved and one can now draw the visible (or hidden) stretches only. All you need to do is to define a function of the torus coordinates `u` and `v`, and pgfplots can be used to draw only the visible parts.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\tikzset{declare function={torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
vtest(\u,\v,\az,\el)=sin(-vcrit1(\u-\az,\el)+\v);
disc(\th,\R,\r)=((pow(\r,2)-pow(\R,2))*pow(cot(\th),2)+% 
pow(\r,2)*(2+pow(tan(\th),2)))/pow(\R,2);% discriminant
umax(\th,\R,\r)=ifthenelse(disc(\th,\R,\r)>0,asin(sqrt(abs(disc(\th,\R,\r)))),0);
}}
\pgfplotsset{%
visible stretch/.style={restrict expr to domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-0.05:1.1}},
hidden stretch/.style={restrict expr to domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-1.1:0.05}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
\begin{axis}[colormap/blackwhite,
   view={40}{60},axis lines=none]
%\typeout{el=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el},az=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}}     
\tikzset{declare function={%
myu(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<108,36,ifthenelse(\t<324,\t-72,ifthenelse(\t<432,252,\t-180)));
myv(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<108,\t,ifthenelse(\t<324,108,ifthenelse(\t<432,\t-216,216)));}}
%   \addplot3[very thick,red,samples y=0,domain=0:576,smooth,samples=46,hidden stretch
%   ]  
%         ({torusx(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
%         {torusy(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
%         {torusz(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)});

       \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,
       samples=61, point meta=z+sin(2*y),
       %surf,shader=flat,
       domain=0:360,y domain=0:360,
       z buffer=sort]
       ({torusx(x,y,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,y,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,y,\R,\r)});
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,30,...,330}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch]  
        ({torusx(x,#1,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1,\R,\r)});}

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,30,...,330}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}

    \addplot3[very thick,red,samples y=0,domain=0:576,smooth,samples=46,visible stretch]  
        ({torusx(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\tikzset{declare function={torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
vtest(\u,\v,\az,\el)=sin(-vcrit1(\u-\az,\el)+\v);
disc(\th,\R,\r)=((pow(\r,2)-pow(\R,2))*pow(cot(\th),2)+% 
pow(\r,2)*(2+pow(tan(\th),2)))/pow(\R,2);% discriminant
umax(\th,\R,\r)=ifthenelse(disc(\th,\R,\r)>0,asin(sqrt(abs(disc(\th,\R,\r)))),0);
}}
\pgfplotsset{%
visible stretch/.style={restrict expr to domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-0.05:1.1}},
hidden stretch/.style={restrict expr to domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-1.1:0.05}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
\begin{axis}[colormap/blackwhite,
   view={40}{60},axis lines=none]
%\typeout{el=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el},az=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}}     
\tikzset{declare function={%
myu(\t)=\t;
myv(\t)=3*\t;}}
    \addplot3[very thick,gray,samples y=0,domain=0:576,smooth,samples=101]  
        ({torusx(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)});

       \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8,
       samples=61, point meta=z+sin(2*y),
       %surf,shader=flat,
       domain=0:360,y domain=0:360,
       z buffer=sort]
       ({torusx(x,y,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,y,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,y,\R,\r)});
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,30,...,330}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch]  
        ({torusx(x,#1,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1,\R,\r)});}

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,30,...,330}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}

    \addplot3[very thick,red,samples y=0,domain=0:576,smooth,samples=101,visible stretch]  
        ({torusx(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(myu(x),myv(x),\R,\r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original**.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{declare function={%
torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
thetacritA(\R,\r)=atan(sqrt(\R/\r-1));
thetacritB(\R,\r)=acos(\r/\R);
ucritA(\R,\r,\th)=180+(90/pi)*sqrt(abs(-(\R^2*pow(cot(\th),2))+4*pow(\r,2)/pow(sin(2*\th),2)))/\R; 
ucritB(\R,\r,\th)=540-ucritA(\R,\r,\th);
umaxA(\R,\r,\th)=asin(sqrt(abs(-pow(cot(\th),2)+4*pow(\r,2)/(pow((sin(2*\th)*\R),2)))));
umaxB(\R,\r,\th)=180-umaxA(\R,\r,\th);}}
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusA}{3}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusB}{1}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\rprime}{1.25}
     % all v curves
     \foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}
     {\draw
        plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth]
    ({torusx(\X,\x,\RadiusA,\RadiusB)},{torusy(\X,\x,\RadiusA,\RadiusB)},{torusz(\X,\x,\RadiusA,\RadiusB)});
     }
     % all u curves
     \foreach \X in {0,30,...,330}
     {\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth]
        ({torusx(\x,\X,\RadiusA,\RadiusB)},{torusy(\x,\X,\RadiusA,\RadiusB)},{torusz(\x,\X,\RadiusA,\RadiusB)});
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

They can be used to discern hidden from visible stretches of something wrapping the torus, as illustrated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485833/121799) where the functions are explained. In case you find it to cumbersome to patch things together you way want to consider switching to asymptote.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{declare function={%
torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
thetacritA(\R,\r)=atan(sqrt(\R/\r-1));
thetacritB(\R,\r)=acos(\r/\R);
ucritA(\R,\r,\th)=180+(90/pi)*sqrt(abs(-(\R^2*pow(cot(\th),2))+4*pow(\r,2)/pow(sin(2*\th),2)))/\R; 
ucritB(\R,\r,\th)=540-ucritA(\R,\r,\th);
umaxA(\R,\r,\th)=asin(sqrt(abs(-pow(cot(\th),2)+4*pow(\r,2)/(pow((sin(2*\th)*\R),2)))));
umaxB(\R,\r,\th)=180-umaxA(\R,\r,\th);}}
\tikzset{3d torus/.style n
args={2}{/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\DDA}{int(sign(sin(thetacritA(#1,#2))-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\DDB}{int(sign(sin(thetacritB(#1,#2))-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)))},
  insert path={
  plot[variable=\x,domain=1:359,smooth cycle,samples=71]
  ({torusx(\x,vcrit1(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
 {torusy(\x,vcrit1(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
 {torusz(\x,vcrit1(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)}) 
   \ifnum\DDA=1
    plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth cycle,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)})    
   \else
   \ifnum\DDB=1 
    plot[variable=\x,domain={umaxA(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)}:{umaxB(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)},smooth,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)})    --
    plot[variable=\x,domain={180+umaxA(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)}:{180+umaxB(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)},smooth,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)})  -- cycle  
    \fi 
   \fi
  }},3d torus stretch/.style n args={2}{/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\DDA}{int(sign(thetacritA(#1,#2)-\tdplotmaintheta))},
  insert path={\ifnum\DDA=-1
   plot[variable=\x,domain={ucritA(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)}:{ucritB(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)},smooth,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)}) 
  \fi 
}}}
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusA}{3}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusB}{1}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\rprime}{1.25}
     \foreach \X/\Y in {105/195,245/335}
     {\draw[line width=2mm,blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=\X:\Y,smooth]
    ({torusx(\x,2*\x,\RadiusA,\rprime)},{torusy(\x,2*\x,\RadiusA,\rprime)},{torusz(\x,2*\x,\RadiusA,\rprime)});}
     \draw[thick,samples=71,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.7,even odd
    rule,3d torus={\RadiusA}{\RadiusB}] ;
    \draw[thick,samples=71,3d torus stretch={\RadiusA}{\RadiusB}];
     \foreach \X/\Y in {-27/107,193/247}
     {\draw[line width=2mm,blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=\X:\Y,smooth]
    ({torusx(\x,2*\x,\RadiusA,\rprime)},{torusy(\x,2*\x,\RadiusA,\rprime)},{torusz(\x,2*\x,\RadiusA,\rprime)});}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time! I am not really looking for a curved or shaded line representing the trefoil though - I'd like the graph to look something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148535/180771 or rather https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70370/180771 . But how do I get the x's and o's in the certain grids, and also the straight red lines? I'd like the 'grid structure' to be preserved. I haven't constructed 3D in LaTeX before so don't really know where to begin!

Comment: I have edited the post to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JpW Well, what have you tried? Believe it or not, I believe to know what a torus is. Probably other people as well, otherwise they would not have closed your question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485485/square-tiling-a-torus. The functions `torusx`, `torusy` and `torusz` provide you with what you need in principle: they map a point with coordinates `(\u,\v)` to the torus. I guess one of the reasons why your question got closed is that it is hard to see effort from your side (I did not vote to close).

Comment: I did not doubt your knowledge of a torus. I just wanted to know how to put the markings on the torus since I'm a total beginner at making 3D plots. Thank you for all your help though. I also believe putting that in paper and scissors showed at least some sort of effort in trying to clarify the question.