# How to plot a donut whose Fig is attached herewith

Tags: plot

How to plot a donut whose Fig is attached herewith

[image]

The donut looks very nice. I want to plot it. The parametric equation of the torus is

$$x = (R + a cos(p)) cos(t);$$
$$y = (R + a cos(p)) sin(t);$$
$$z = a sin(p);$$
where $t,p\in [0, 2\pi]$
How to do that?
**EDIT:**
What I have tried is given below:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{comment}
    
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.16}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    view={60}{30},
    ]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    p domain=0:2*pi,
    samples=101,
    samples x=2,R=5,a=2
]
({(R + a*cos(deg(p)))*cos(deg(x))},
{(R + a*cos(deg(p)))*sin(deg(x))},{a*sin(deg(x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Duplicates https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27597/drawing-checkered-torus-doughnut https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247997/drawing-cross-sections-of-contours-over-torus https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus

Comment: Do-this-complicated-thing-for-me questions are often less than well-received (unless they involve something cute like a duck). Please show us what you've tried or hire somebody to create your images from scratch, if you don't want to. Also, you shouldn't use `$$` in LaTeX and/or MathJax is not enabled on this site.

Comment: the codes are not executing \usepackage{pst-solides3d} in overleaf

Comment: Also here the Fig is very attractive that the fig in the links

Comment: You can't use `pst-solides3d` with `pdflatex`. Pick one of the Ti*k*Z solutions or use a different engine.

Comment: @cfr Would you please post a code for getting this nice figure

Comment: As I've already explained, that's not how this site works. Frankly, I also think you're bizarrely unappreciative of the ***many*** answers you've been directed to, including an entire page of possibilities, many of which I find rather attractive. If you want to create something different, you have to put the time in to learn how to use the tools or put the money up for a professional. Yes, people sometimes get lucky and somebody draws something for them if the question interests them, but something like this is a lot of work. If you put the effort in, people will help when you get stuck.

Comment: Start with something simple. Work through the tutorials in the Ti*k*Z manual until you can draw basic stuff. Then you can start looking at Ti*k*Z's 3D and plotting stuff or at pgfplots. That's if you want to learn pgf/Ti*k*Z. Obviously, if you prefer one of the other tools, you should start there. If you need something quickly `\includegraphics` is your friend. If you need to modify it, try Inkscape or equivalent. (Inkscape can produce Ti*k*Z code, though it is not very wieldy in my experience.)

Comment: @cfr What I have tried is edited above. Thank you.

Comment: @math131, this community voted to close your question, as there were many duplicates (answered before). Voting to reopen will require, at least if I had to, to see, that you worked with the at least 14 or so proposals. 11: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus; 2: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27597/drawing-checkered-torus-doughnut; 1 Q: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247997/drawing-cross-sections-of-contours-over-torus. // It's also a good idea to include a screenshot of your current result. // See your previous questions.